# Is there a way to send a file through httpsCallable in firebase funcitons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When the user uploads an image and presses submit in a form on the frontend (javascript), I want a `this.functions.httpsCallable('uploadImage')` to be triggered. However, I'm not sure how to send the file through `httpsCallable`.

The path of execution should be like this:

- The user chooses a local file and presses submit.
- On submit, a `this.functions.httpsCallable('uploadImage')({imageFile})` is called.
- The function receives the image and sends back an appropriate response.
- The frontend prints the response to the user.

If it helps I'm using React with Gatsby for frontend.

Answer (score 1):

Since callable functions can only send JSON data back and forth, you will have to convert the file into something compatible with JSON.  JSON can't hold arbitrary binary data, so you would have to (for example) base64 encode the file data to store as a string property in JSON.

Comment: Could it possibly be faster if instead, I used ```functions.https.onRequest```?

Comment: If you mean *easier*, possibly.  You could use existing libraries that do http file uploads with form data.